# Publish on Facebook Wall without login button

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to post some text on Facebook Wall.

I've seen the tutorials from "Facebook Developers" but they suggest having a button to Login and another one to publish feed. Unfortunately, it's not what I want.

What I want is to click on a button I made and publish directly on the Facebook Wall without having to go through a Login button.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Share intent](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) for this.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```